# Access local mp3 file with <AUDIO> or <a href> from HTML 5

Tags: firefox, mp3, html5-audio

I have the following basic html code

```html
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="file://C:/temp/Test.mp3">Play (open new Tab, show Control, start automatically)</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Show (working) Control:
        <audio controls src='file://C:/temp/Test.mp3'></audio>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If I save this code in a local `test.html` and double click it, my default webbrowser FireFox (v41) open it. I can click on the first URL and then a new tab will open and play this local available `test.mp3` as wished.
I can click on the second control and play the same song on the same page without any problems.

As soon as I upload the `test.html` to a webserver (local or from internet provider), both links doesn't work anymore. The second song doesn't even show the control anymore.

How do I have to write my html code to play my local stored mp3?

I have full access to everything, but whatever I try, FireFox tells me about a security problem and 'can't link or load this file' in the browser console (CTRL-SHIFT-j).

What I also don't understand:
If I enter `file://C:/temp/Test.mp3` manually as an address in FireFox the *.mp3 plays fine. Why should it be forbidden from my local webserver?

I know about this http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work but this seems not to work anymore for the actual FireFox version.

Or do you know a special syntax to access local audio (not html oder css) files? It would not be a problem for me to change some firefox settings or other permissions on my machine.

Comment: According to the page you linked, the setting needs to be updated to allow this behavior in your browser.  Did you update the setting in your browser?

Comment: Which settings exactly? The 3 lines user_pref in the file user.js?